# How Do I Get This Program To Draw 10 Ellipses in Python?

Tags: python, list, class, loops, pygame

> I'm working on this Chapter 12 Classes Exercise Step #11 in Program
>   Arcade games and I'm having trouble displaying 10 ellipses which I'm
>   trying to do through the parent class of Rectangle. I'm just getting
>   10 rectangles right now. I know the problem is either in lines 34-37,
>   60-62, or 78-81.  The whole problem is laid out in the link below

http://www.programarcadegames.com/index.php?chapter=lab_classes_and_graphics&lang=en

```
import pygame
from random import randrange 

#Colors
black = (0, 0, 0)
white = (255, 255, 255)
green = (0, 255, 0)
red = (255, 0, 0)

pygame.init()

#Set width and height of screen
size = (700, 500)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

pygame.display.set_caption("Classes")

class Rectangle():

    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 0
        self.y = 0
        self.change_x = 0
        self.change_y = 0
        self.width = 0
        self.height = 0
        self.color = [0, 255, 0]
    def draw(self, screen):
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, self.color, [self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height])
    def move(self):
        self.x = self.x + self.change_x
        self.y = self.y + self.change_y

class Ellipse(Rectangle):

    def draw(self, screen):
        pygame.draw.ellipse(screen, self.color, [self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height])



#Loop until user clicks close
done = False

#Manage how fast screen updates
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

my_list = []
for i in range(10):

    my_object = Rectangle()
    my_object.x = randrange(0, 701)
    my_object.y = randrange(0, 501)
    my_object.change_x = randrange(-3, 3)
    my_object.change_y = randrange(-3, 3)
    my_object.width = randrange(20, 71)
    my_object.height = randrange(20, 71)
    my_object.color = [0, 255, 0]
    my_list.append(my_object)

for i in range(10):

    my_ellipse = Ellipse()
    my_list.append(my_ellipse)

#Main Program Loop
while not done:
    #Main event loop
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True

    #Game logic goes here

    #Screen clearing code or background image goes here
    screen.fill(black)

    #drawing code goes here
    for my_object in my_list:
        my_object.draw(screen)
        my_ellipse.draw(screen)
        my_object.move()


    #update and display drawn screen
    pygame.display.flip()

    #limit to 60 frames per second
    clock.tick(60)

#close the window and quit
pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 2):

The code you've shown technically *does* draw 10 ellipses, but they're zero by zero pixel ones, so you don't actually see anything.

You need to change your setup code to set the attributes of the `Ellipse` instances you create in your loop to something useful, just like the previous loop does for the 10 rectangles it creates. Without the setup, you're just using the default values (mostly zeros).